при попытке загрузки файла с сервера выдает сообщение о не подключенной службе FileStream
на сервере elsa 3.3 при попытке загрузки файлов с сервера через встроенную активити HTTP File Response выдает ошибку
No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultExecutor`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileStreamResult]' has been registered.
StackTrace  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileStreamResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context) at Elsa.Http.WriteFileHttpResponse.SendFileStream(ActivityExecutionContext context, HttpContext httpContext, Stream source, String contentType, String filename, EntityTagHeaderValue eTag) at Elsa.Http.WriteFileHttpResponse.SendSingleFileAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context, HttpContext httpContext, Func`1 downloadableFunc) at Elsa.Http.WriteFileHttpResponse.SendDownloadablesAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context, HttpContext httpContext, IEnumerable`1 downloadables) at Elsa.Http.WriteFileHttpResponse.WriteResponseAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context, HttpContext httpContext) at Elsa.Http.WriteFileHttpResponse.ExecuteAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context) at Elsa.Workflows.Activity.Elsa.Workflows.IActivity.ExecuteAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context) at Elsa.Workflows.Middleware.Activities.DefaultActivityInvokerMiddleware.ExecuteActivityAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context) at Elsa.Workflows.Runtime.Middleware.Activities.BackgroundActivityInvokerMiddleware.ExecuteActivityAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context) at Elsa.Workflows.Middleware.Activities.DefaultActivityInvokerMiddleware.InvokeAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context) at Elsa.Workflows.Middleware.Activities.NotificationPublishingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context) at Elsa.Workflows.Middleware.Activities.ExecutionLogMiddleware.InvokeAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context) at Elsa.Workflows.Middleware.Activities.ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context)

